# Scala way for converting Long to ArrayByte

Tags: arrays, scala

I'm trying to convert the Long to array byte. This code block is working but this solution is a Java solution. I'm looking for a good solution in Scala. How can I convert the Long to array byte in Scala way?

```
val arrayByteFromLong: Array[Byte] = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(myLong).array()
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine for Scala too (I'd prefer it to Federico's answer). One exception is if you are looking for code which will work in Scala.js/Scala Native.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can leverage `scala.math.BigInt`:

```scala
import scala.math.BigInt

val arrayByteFromLong: Array[Byte] = BigInt(myLong).toByteArray
```

If you want to also pad the array to `8` `Byte`s you can do (quick-and-dirty not so efficient version):

```scala
arrayByteFromLong.reverse.padTo(8,0).reverse
```

Comment: Just as easy to get back via `BigInt(arrayByteFromLong).toLong`

Comment: note that BigInt.toByteArray and ButeBuffer have different padding rules:

`BigInt(-4227595774L).toByteArray` => `Array(-1, 4, 4, 2, 2)`

`ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(-4227595774L).array()` => `Array[Byte] = Array(-1, -1, -1, -1, 4, 4, 2, 2)`